# Having an issue with get back RefreshToken in google calendar API

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am having an issue with fetching refresh access token from google oauth2.0 calendar API. My Code is:

```
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
 $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {

    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);

    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

      // Refresh the token if it's expired.
      if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                try {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                }
                catch(Exception $e) { die("Error is: ".$e->getMessage()); }  

        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
      }

    $authUrl = '';
    return $client;

  }
}
```

I am getting Exception at `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken`. Where i am using try catch. Getting Exception `Error is: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken`. As per threads on github, i have also passed `$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH); $client->setAccessType('offline');` with the client object. 
Please help to solve this error.

Comment: It seems your `$client->getRefreshToken()` doesn't include a `refresh_token` part. Please check how you saved your access token to `$credentialsPath`, the credentials file is missing the refresh token. You have to correct this. Maybe you can share here the code you use to write the credentials file.

Answer (score 0):

> $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());

$client->getRefreshToken() should be stored in a var/object before being used by $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()

```
$refresh_token = $client->getRefreshToken(); 
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refresh_token);
```